# Displays Incorrect Results in Cucumber Extent Report in

Tags: selenium, cucumber, extentreports

Currently I am using Cucumber Extent Report from com.vimalselvam and using the latest version 3.0.1.

1. In my feature File I have scenario Outline with Examples and 3 rows Inside the examples.

Now If one scenarios fails and other two pass then the Extent Report displays the Report as 3 Scenarios Failed and 0 Passed.But Actually only one scenario failed and then rest of the scenario passed.
[image]

Can anyone help me to fix this issue or recommended another Reporting tool which covers this Scenario Outline as well.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: See here https://github.com/email2vimalraj/CucumberExtentReporter/issues/56. Would suggest to ask here.

Comment: This was a bug in the API, which has been fixed for version starting 3.1.1. Please see here:  https://github.com/email2vimalraj/CucumberExtentReporter/issues/60

Comment: Changed the version number from 3.0.1 to 3.1.1 in pom.xml. But it shows error in pom.xml Once I change the version number

Comment: Still I got stuck on the above Issue.Can you please let me once the new version gets updated.

Comment: What is the error in the pom.xml?